# PHP Array Keys Wildcard

Tags: php, arrays, wildcard

I have a multidimensional array which has some predictable key and some unpredictable.

An example would be:

```
$myarray[0] => array ( [prefix-number] => value ... )
$myarray[1] => array ( [prefix-number] => value ... )
```

The first part of the array will always start at 0 and go up from there... that is by design.  The second part of the array has a set prefix which is a label which is predictable but the number after the dash is not.  For array entry 0 it could be number 3 or 6.  For entry 0 all numbers will be the same.  What I'm looking to do is a for statement that will go through each element in the array checking the sub key prefixes but not worry about the number... for example:

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($myarray); $i++) {

     if($myarray[$i]['prefix-'%] == "") {

           $error = "error";

     }
}
```

I want the % in there to be a wildcard where the if statement won't worry about what is there just the prefix which is in quotes.

I realize I can use substr on the array key and get just the prefix out but I was hoping that wildcards were allowed in some way.

Comment: Writing the code to use `substr` would've taken less time than writing up this question... No, there's no wildcarding built-in like that. Something like `substr` or `preg_match` will be needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the criticism!

I ended up storing the second key in a variable so it looks like:

```
$arraykey = key($myarray[$i]);
if($myarray[$i][$arraykey] == "") { ....
```